# LINQ expression with mulitple count

Tags: c#, linq, count, sum

I will appreciate help on writing the following SQL query with multiple `count` into a **single** LINQ expression

```sql
select count(MemoNo) as totalOrder, 
count(distinct shopId) as shops, 
sum(TotalAmount) as totalAmount 
from Sales;
```

**Sample data**

```
| MemoNo | shopId | TotalAmount |
|-------------------------------|
|     a10|      s2|          200|
|     a11|      s2|          220|
|     a12|      s3|          100|
|     a13|      s3|           20|
|     a14|      s3|          100|
|     a15|      s4|           50|
|     a16|      s4|           20|
|     a17|      s4|           90|
```

**Sample output** should look like this

```
| totalOrder | shops | totalAmount | 
|------------|-------|-------------|
|          8 |     3 |          800|
```

Comment: You should give us some sample data with the corresponding result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
var totalOrder = Sales.Select(p => p.MemoNo).Count();
var shop = Sales.Select(p => p.shopId).Distinct().Count();
var totalAmount = Sales.Sum(p => p.TotalAmount);
```

**Updated**

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TkxiS5)

```
    var tempData  = Sales.GroupBy(p => p.shopId).Select(g => new 
    {
       shops = g.Count(),
       totalAmount = g.Sum(p => p.TotalAmount),
       totalOrder = g.Count()
    });
    var result = new 
    {
        totalOrder = tempData.Sum(p => p.totalOrder),
        shops = tempData.Count(),
        totalAmount = tempData.Sum(p => p.totalAmount)
    };
    // Output: { totalOrder = 8, shops = 3, totalAmount = 800 }
```

Comment: Instead of 3 separate expression Is it not possible with a single LINQ expression?

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at. Anyway, Give me your sample data with the corresponding result would will helpful.

Comment: your last update didn't work. I updated the question with sample data, please check

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at @Mahabubul Hasan